# Proceso en segundo plano en java con swing

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos, procesos-en-segundo-plano

estoy desarrollando une pequeña prueba en la que pulso un botón en java swing y comience a hacer una tarea en segundo plano, mientras se ejecuta la tarea en segundo plano quiero seguir interactuando con la ventana. Sin embargo al desarrollarlo me di cuenta que si pulso el botón, se queda la ventana congelada hasta que acabe el proceso. Dejo por aquí el código para que me podáis aconsejar sobre que debo hacer.

La clase en segundo plano:

```
public class Descarga extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Decargando en segundo plano");
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

La ventana:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class Ventana extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public Ventana() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 370, 156);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Empezar descarga");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Descarga h2 = new Descarga();
                h2.run();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(81, 72, 199, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
        
        JCheckBox chckbxOtraCosa = new JCheckBox("Seguir haciendo cosas");
        chckbxOtraCosa.setBounds(81, 8, 193, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxOtraCosa);
    }
}
```

La clase para ejecutar el programa:

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
        
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que estás invocando el método `run()`, pero hacer esto simplemente va a ejecutar el código de dicho método (sin crear un nuevo hilo). Esto es incorrecto tomando en cuenta que lo que quieres hacer es que el código definido en ese método `run()` se ejecute en un hilo distinto al hilo donde corre la interfaz gráfica.

Para que se cree un hilo nuevo siempre tienes que usar el método [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) y una vez que dicho hilo se inicie entonces este será quien ejecute el código que definiste en el método [`run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#run()).

```java
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Empezar descarga");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Descarga h2 = new Descarga();
        h2.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tienes razón, que Dios le bendiga.